# GPUImage and performance with external accessory

Tags: objective-c, iphone, grand-central-dispatch, gpuimage

What is the best way to render a series of frames coming from an external accessory using GPUImage?  I am looking for the best performance I can get with a series of frames technically a series of UIImages but they are coming from an external accessory after processing.  But the processing is not in GPUImage but I still need to get the best performance I can.

Comment: Doesn't that also depend on the external accessory? Maybe you be more specific?

Comment: That does not really matter because what I am looking for is something that deals with a source of UIImage's and pipes those images to GPUImage.  So the source could really be anything but just a source of UIImage's that are piped to GPUImage one image at a time.  IF UIImage's do not work it could be a series of ARGB or RGBA byte arrays too.

Comment: What format do you get from your device? A byte array? If it's a byte array do you create the UIImage using `CGBitmapContextCreateWithData`? Lastly, are all the frames the same size? If that is all true you can probably get pretty good performance using the `GPUImagePicture+TextureSubimage.h` category I contributed to GPUImage to reuse a single texture for every frame. This will remove the overhead of creating a `GPUImagePicture` each frame. If you need more specific help let me know

Comment: Nobody wants my bounty?  After some further investigation, I think I can probably answer my own question at this point but I won't because I want to see if someone else can answer it.  That will validate what I think needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Since it has been a while, I thought I would answer my own question.  Basically I wound up using GPUImageRawDataInput.  Here is the code chunk that worked for me ->

```
unsigned char *dataBuffer = ... // 640X480X4 bytes RGBA data

if (!initialized) {
    initialized = true;

    self.rawDataInput = [[GPUImageRawDataInput alloc] initWithBytes:dataBuffer
        size:CGSizeMake(640.0f, 480.0f) pixelFormat:GPUPixelFormatRGBA];

    [self.imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2)];

    [self.rawDataInput addTarget:self.imageView];
}
else {
    [self.rawDataInput updateDataFromBytes:dataBuffer size:CGSizeMake(640.0f, 480.0f)];
}

[self.rawDataInput processData];
```